# Maven and Jetty work on windows machine, not on Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, maven

The way I'm developing is: writing my code on my windows machine with Eclipse Mars and using git to copy the repo to the actual web server. When I enter mvn jetty:run on my windows, it works fine, jetty starts up. When I enter sudo mvn jetty:run on linux, I get PluginContainerException. I tried looking at Apache's support page for that, but I didn't really get anywhere. Here's my pom file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>my name</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>repo2_maven_org</id>
           <url>http://repo2.maven.org/maven2</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version></dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version></dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version></plugin></plugins></build>
</project>
```

Full Exception Message:

```
INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.176 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-12T17:52:06+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/20M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.v20150612:run (default-cli) on project angular-gantt-websocket: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.v20150612:run failed: Unable to load the mojo 'run' in the plugin 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.v20150612' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/eclipse/jetty/maven/plugin/JettyRunMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.v20150612
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-maven-plugin-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.1.1/sisu-inject-bean-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.9.4/sisu-guice-2.9.4-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.6/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.11/aether-util-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/3.1/maven-plugin-tools-api-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/root/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-util-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-webapp-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-xml-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-servlet-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-quickstart/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-quickstart-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jaas/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-jaas-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-security-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-plus/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-plus-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jndi/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-jndi-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-server-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-http-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-io-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jmx/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-jmx-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-annotations/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-annotations-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/root/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.1/asm-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.1/asm-commons-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.1/asm-tree-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-server-impl/9.3.0.v20150612/javax-websocket-server-impl-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-client-impl/9.3.0.v20150612/javax-websocket-client-impl-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/root/.m2/repository/javax/websocket/javax.websocket-api/1.0/javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-server/9.3.0.v20150612/websocket-server-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.3.0.v20150612/websocket-common-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.3.0.v20150612/websocket-api-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.3.0.v20150612/websocket-client-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-servlet/9.3.0.v20150612/websocket-servlet-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/apache-jsp/9.3.0.v20150612/apache-jsp-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-schemas/3.1.M0/jetty-schemas-3.1.M0.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-jsp/8.0.20.M0/apache-jsp-8.0.20.M0.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-el/8.0.20.M0/apache-el-8.0.20.M0.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/org.eclipse.jdt.core/3.8.2.v20130121/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/apache-jstl/9.3.0.v20150612/apache-jstl-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-spec/1.2.1/taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.1/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/root/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

After fixing the initial error I received this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project angular-gantt-websocket: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

Comment: Could you include the full exception that you're seeing?

Comment: please execute this commands: javac -version and then sudo javac -version

Comment: I am so stupid, I accidentally installed the jre instead of the jdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part is this

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.v20150612:run (default-cli) on project angular-gantt-websocket: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.v20150612:run failed: Unable to load the mojo 'run' in the plugin 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.v20150612' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/eclipse/jetty/maven/plugin/JettyRunMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

It says the class file is compiled against a different version of Java. Check your Java runtime or JDK version.

Comment: I did this and that fixed that error, but now I'm getting a MojoFailureException, saying that there is no compiler. That being said when I enter mvn -version, it says I have jdk 1.8.xx

Comment: Run javac -version and see what compiler is installed. Verify JAVA_HOME points to JDK installation and not JRE. Also use "which java" and "which javac" to find and correct path variables.